# FullCalendar anchor's title property empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

Trying to use [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) on our website. Despite setting the `title` property of the `event` object in the source API, the rendered `a` tag has empty `title` property. Like below.

`<a href="#" class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-not-end" data-original-title="" title=""><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">10a</span> <span class="fc-title">some event</span></div></a>`

**The title text shows up fine in the calendar boxes, but the issue is because of empty `title` property in `a` tag, hovering over the event does not show the entire title.**

And no, I don't want to try qtip or bootstrap popover yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [eventRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) function will let you set the title

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.attr('title', event.title);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9wam5cng/

Answer (score 1):

You can set default title for empty list with noEventsMessage property.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'list' ],
  defaultView: 'listWeek',
  noEventsMessage: 'No event found !!!!!!',  <--------------this property-----------
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2019-08-12T14:30:00',
      extendedProps: {
        status: 'done'
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: '2019-08-13T07:00:00',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green'
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for FullCalendar5

Rename `noEventsMessage` to `noEventsContent`

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'list' ],
  defaultView: 'listWeek',
  noEventsContent: 'No event found !!!!!!',  <--------------this property-----------
  events: [
```